# Django iterate comma-separated list in template

Tags: django

My Django project has a field for "Tags," where users can add tags for their posts. Currently this is stored in a models.CharField(max_length=200) field in my model.

What I'd like to do is have it so that when the post is displayed, each word is printed with its own URL to sort the posts by that particular tag. For example, each post also has a "Category" models.CharField where they can select a category from a dropdown list, which is made into a URL in the post.

For example in my Views.py:

```
@login_required
def category(request, category):
    thisuser = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        category = request.POST['category']
    else:
        category = ''
    following = Follow.objects.filter(follower=thisuser).order_by('-pubdate')
    followers = Follow.objects.filter(who_following=thisuser).order_by('-pubdate')

    posts = Post.objects.filter(category__contains=category)

    args = {'posts': posts, 'thisuser': thisuser, 'following': following, 'followers': followers}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['category'] = category

    return render_to_response('lobby.html', args)
```

and in my template:

```
<a href="/lobby/posts/category/{{post.category|lower}}/">Category: {{post.category}}</a>
```

Is there a {% for %} template tag I can use to split the values in the tags field by comma and then render each of them as their own instance? Or would I have to do something else, like make a relational database for Tags (since a post can have multiple tags) and then iterate them all by Post ID?

Comment: "Is there a `{% for %}` template tag..."? Well, [you didn't look very hard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)!

Comment: I guess the question is how do I turn that into a list that django can iterate? Right now it's saving something like "Website, Updates" into the field but I want django to see that as a list so I can iterate it. That's where I'm confused.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, re-read that whole sentence. He's looking for something more than the {% for %} tag

Comment: @SohanJain I did read the whole sentence. I can't tell much about what OP is looking for because the code for `Tag` is missing (it's just described as a `models.CharField` somewhere), which is why I _commented_ (not answered) on the part I could understand -- is there a template tag like `{% for %}` something that can iterate through a list? Yes. It's on the Django list of default tags and filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database design-wise, the best option is to have a separate model for Tags. This will let you search/sort/filter by tags more easily.

However, if you need a quick fix, you'll have to push that "split by comma" logic to your view/model, like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.CharField(...)

    def split_tags(self):
        return self.tags.split(',')


# in your template:
{% for tag in post.split_tags %} {{ tag }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So would the best suggestion long-term be to create a Tag model, split the input by comma, create a new tag object for each, and then iterate all of the related objects using for the {% for %} command?

Comment: Tagging can get incredibly complex, especially when you want to search by tags. You'll ultimately want to normalize them (are the tags "UCLA" and "University of California Los Angeles" both the same tag? How do we get them to mean the same thing?). If you don't need to account for this complexity, then I'd still try to use an existing tagging library like `django-taggit`, as someone below commented. You'd have tags as an M2M on Post. Then you can say: "give me all posts that are tagged with "UCLA". This is difficult without having a separate model for the tag

Comment: Old post, but this is worth of mention. Very elegant solution. Helped me alot to solve my issue, plus gave me a bunch of ideas for future stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like

```
class Post(models.Model):
    def categories(self):
        return self.category.split(',')
```

and then

```
{% for category in post.categories %}
```

but I strongly advice using a m2m relationship in your case. You can use an app like django-taggit to help you with that.

Comment: If I built a separate model for tags, what would be the advantage of having it be M2M over just using a standard charField and making each tag its own object?

Comment: It's easier to make certain type of queries.
Let's say you want to retrieve related items ordered by the number of tags they have in common. It would be easier to query your relational model. 
In general, whenever you can make a relation table, you should.